# Import a scheduled task from XML in Inno Setup

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, pascal, windows-task-scheduler

I'm using [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php) to create an installer for my application

**How can I add a scheduled task to the users PC from an XML file using Inno Setup?**

I have created a scheduled task on my development PC and exported it to a file named `ServerSwitchScheduledTask.xml`

I have included this file in my install. I am currently placing a copy of this file in the application's folder like this:

```
[Setup]
PrivilegesRequired=admin

[Files] 
Source: "ServerSwitchScheduledTask.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

This works as expected. However, I would also like to actually import the scheduled task to the users PC.

I tried this

```
Filename: "schtasks.exe"; \
    Parameters: "/create /XML {app}\ServerSwitchScheduledTask.xml /tn ServerSwitch";
```

Which causes no errors that I can see (in the debug output for Inno Setup) but does not add the scheduled task to the users PC

Then I read the docs for [schtasks.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx)

> /RP [password]
>
> A value that specifies the password for the user specified with the /RU parameter. To prompt for the password, the value must be either "*" or no value. This password is ignored for the system account. This parameter must be combined with either /RU or the /XML switch.

So I changed it to:

```
Filename: "schtasks.exe"; \
    Parameters: "/create /RP * /XML {app}\ServerSwitchScheduledTask.xml /tn ServerSwitch";
```

I expected this to prompt for a password on install but it does not and still does not generate an error or add the scheduled task.

---

I have also tried using the code section like this:

```pascal
[Files] 
Source: "ServerSwitchScheduledTask.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; BeforeInstall: BeforeInstallProc

[Code]
procedure BeforeInstallProc;

var
  ResultCode: Integer;     
begin
  { Launch Notepad and wait for it to terminate }
  if Exec('{sys}\schtasks.exe', '/create /XML ServerSwitchScheduledTask.xml /tn ServerSwitch', '', SW_SHOW,
     ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
  begin
    { handle success if necessary; ResultCode contains the exit code }
    MsgBox('Task sceduled', mbConfirmation, MB_OK);
  end
  else begin

  if MsgBox('Unable to schedule Server Switch to start on login. See AUTO RUN  section of the REAM_ME#13#10#13#10Continue anyway?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = IDYES then
  begin
    { user clicked Yes }
  end;
    { handle failure if necessary; ResultCode contains the error code }
    WizardForm.Close;    
    { MsgBox('Intsataller says: ', mbCriticalError, MB_OK); }
  end;
end;
```

I get the `Unable to schedule Server.....`
message displayed with this method

---

I also tried like this:

```pascal
[Files] 
Source: "ServerSwitchScheduledTask.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; AfterInstall: AfterInstallProc

[Code]
procedure AfterInstallProc;

var
  ResultCode: Integer;     
begin
  { Launch Notepad and wait for it to terminate }
  if Exec('{sys}\schtasks.exe', '/create /XML "C:\Program Files (x86)\Server Tools\ServerSwitchScheduledTask.xml" /tn ServerSwitch', '', SW_SHOW,
     ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
  begin
    { handle success if necessary; ResultCode contains the exit code }
    MsgBox('Task sceduled', mbConfirmation, MB_OK);
  end
  else begin

  if MsgBox('Unable to schedule Server Switch to start on login. See AUTO RUN  section of the REAM_ME. Continue anyway?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = IDYES then
  begin
    { user clicked Yes }
  end;
    { handle failure if necessary; ResultCode contains the error code }
    WizardForm.Close;    
    { MsgBox('Intsataller says: ', mbCriticalError, MB_OK); }
  end;
end;
```

This also failed, however, with the files installed, I can call it from the command line successfully like this:

```
C:\Windows\system32>schtasks.exe /create /XML "C:\Program Files (x86)\Server Too
ls\ServerSwitchScheduledTask.xml" /TN ServerSwitch
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "ServerSwitch" has successfully been created.
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Your Inno Setup scripts works for me for a simple task exported from Windows Scheduler. So I assume the problem is specific to your particular task and has actually nothing to so with Inno Setup as such. Does your `schtasks` command work for you if you execute it from an elevated command prompt (`cmd.exe`)?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I think you're right, I feel like this has to do with spaces in the path to the file. I'm installing the xml file to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Server Too
ls\ServerSwitchScheduledTask.xml` I can run it from there with the command line like `C:\Windows\system32>schtasks.exe /create /XML "C:\Program Files (x86)\Server Too
ls\ServerSwitchScheduledTask.xml" /TN ServerSwitch
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "ServerSwitch" has successfully been created.` but Im not sure how to do that in the Exec() command or in the `[Run]` section

Comment: Are you running the installer using the same account you tested the `schtasks.exe` from command-line? Is there no more details than the "Unable to schedule Server"?

Comment: Can you try to execute command prompt from the `Run` section (like `Filename: "{cmd}"`), execute the installed and once the command prompt pops up, run the `schtasks` manually using the installed `ServerSwitchScheduledTask.xml`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes doing it that way I get: `SUCCESS: The scheduled task "ServerSwitch" has successfully been created.` And when I do it like before, I get a ResultCOde of 267. So it must be an issue with the spaces in the path right? How do I fix that?

Comment: What exact command did you use?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl `schtasks.exe /create /XML "C:\Program Files (x86)\Server Too
ls\ServerSwitchScheduledTask.xml" /TN ServerSwitch`

Comment: I know how to escape it for the command line like that But cant seem to get it right for the RUN or CODE sections

Comment: For that the `Run` section equivalent is `Filename: "schtasks.exe"; Parameters: "/create /XML ""{app}\ServerSwitchScheduledTask.xml"" /TN ServerSwitch"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a complete working example, see
[How to add a scheduled task on network connection/disconnection event with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43253725/850848).

---

To answer your individual questions/issues:

As you guessed yourself, you need to deal with spaces in the path to the XML file.

You need to wrap the path to double-quotes.

In `Run` section, where the argument list itself is wrapped to double-quotes, you need to double the inner double-quotes:

```
[Run]
Filename: "schtasks.exe"; \
    Parameters: "/create /XML ""{app}\ServerSwitchScheduledTask.xml"" /TN ServerSwitch"
```

See [Parameters in Sections](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=params) in Inno Setup documentation.

---

You have the quotes right in your `AfterInstall` attempt, but there you have the executable path wrong.

The constants are not automatically resolved in `Code` section.

So either you just do not specify a path (like you do in `Run`):

```pascal
if Exec('schtasks.exe', ...)
```

or use [`ExpandConstant` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant):

```pascal
if Exec(ExpandConstant('{sys}\schtasks.exe'), ...)
```

You should use that for the parameters anyway, to resolve the installation folder:

```pascal
if Exec(
     'schtasks.exe',
     ExpandConstant('/create /XML "{app}\ServerSwitchScheduledTask.xml" /tn ServerSwitch'),
     ...)
```

---

As for the `BeforeInstall`, that's simply a nonsense, as the XML file is not installed yet at that moment.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been at it all day and could not get this working.  I tried everything you mentioned just not in the right combinations.

Comment: I noticed that if I want to do this after the install (giving the user a choice at the end) using the  `postinstall` flag, I have to also supply the `runascurrentuser` flag. I'm thinking this is because the call made post install is in a different context and no longer has the installers admin rights by default. Is that accurate?

Comment: Correct, as per [the documentation for Run section](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection): `runascurrentuser` is the default when `postinstall` is **not used** and the `runasoriginaluser` is the default when `postinstall` is **used**.