# Inno Setup change an existing Windows Scheduled Task to run when on battery power

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, inno-setup, taskscheduler, pascalscript

By default Windows Scheduled Tasks are created with the 'Start the task only if the computer is on AC power' setting enabled.

[image: Scheduled Task]

It is not possible to change this setting using `schtasks.exe`, which would have been the simple solution. However, it appears that it is possible to do this through the Windows API [`ITaskSettings::get_DisallowStartIfOnBatteries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nf-taskschd-itasksettings-get_disallowstartifonbatteries) method. Can this be imported into Inno Setup in order to disable this setting, on an **existing** Scheduled Task, and allow it to run when the computer is on battery power? If so, how would this be done? Or is there another way to change this setting using Inno Setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's possible to set that option using `schtasks`. You just have to use XML definition of the task.

For your particular option, you need to set `DisallowStartIfOnBatteries` to `false`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <!-- ... -->
  <Settings>
    <!-- ... -->
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
  </Settings>
</Task>
```

For more, see [How to add a scheduled task on network connection/disconnection event with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43253725/850848).

---

I didn't find a way to use the API to modify an existing task. This does not have any effect:

```pascal
var
  TaskService: Variant;
  Folder: Variant;
  Task: Variant;
begin
  TaskService := CreateOleObject('Schedule.Service');
  TaskService.Connect();
  Folder := TaskService.GetFolder('\');
  Task := Folder.GetTask('test');
  Task.Definition.Settings.DisallowStartIfOnBatteries := False;
end;
```

Comment: Maybe I should have been clearer in the question and said I was already aware of the XML option for `schtasks.exe`. The trouble with that is it is only really useful if you are creating a new Scheduled Task and not if you are trying to change an existing one.

Comment: This may work actually. To export the task to XML (assuming that can be done from the command line), delete the original task, edit the XML in code and recreate it. However, it seems quite a convoluted way to do it.

Comment: To export an XML of an existing task, use `schtasks /query /tn "name" /xml one`.

Comment: Is there not another more elegant way to do this? It seems like an awfully convoluted way to achieve it.

Comment: I haven't found any elegant way to modify advanced settings of an existing scheduled task.

Comment: I take it the Windows API method I mentioned in the question wouldn't work then? Unfortunately, I don't really understand how to go about importing Windows APIs and translating from the C++ they are documented in to PascalScript,

Comment: I didn't find a way to modify settings of an existing task. See my updated answer.

Comment: Looks like the convoluted method may be the only way then. Thank you Martin.